# Finite State Machine (FSM) bit sequence detector for a stream of several bits

Tags: sequence-detector

Typically, drawing out a FSM is the solution to this problem. However, my question here is its implementation.
I thought of two ways but i am not sure if they were correct.

1. typical FSM, truth table for current states, next states and 1-bit output. Develop the logic function for each output and implement the logic function with and gates and etc.
2. 5 consecutive flipflops connect to a single mux as its control signal. Each stage contribute 1 bits to the control. Until the control signal from these flipflops matches the required pattern, select and output 1.

Which way is correct since most often I see people use the 1st method.

Which method is best to design a sequence detector for a stream of several bits? For example: 10110

Comment: in which context? **For which purpose**? (I ask that question under nearly every question, hence the **bold**) I mean, both things, if reduced to the minimum gates necessary, should be *identical*, but you usually use either depending on the tools and components at hand.

Comment: I understand. Maybe I am not very clear headed about my purpose. These are 2 different design ideas no matter how to implement and realize in reality using any kind of tools. I just wanna know which idea is more preferred in industry and why. Moreover, I got educated to use FSM,but it seems the shift register is easier.

Comment: you don't *seem* to understand. "Industry" is not an application. "Industry" doesn't prefer anything, hence. The point is that you need to specify on what you need to implement and for what purpose to get a meaningful info on what you would use for that.

Comment: it seems it's you that don't understand. I basically discussed  two ideas. I am asking in a general way and I think others understand and they give me the answer I wanted. First, I want to know if these two ideas are doable, and second, what is their difference. More importantly, there is no need to know what to use for implementation and under what context. There are always a clear cut between two ideas. There are many ideas to design a FIFO, to design a pipeline, using ROB , using RMT or not, using which predictor. There is no need to know how exactly they are implemented to know difference.

Comment: you think you know more and you are the boss. That's cool. But what you said is not what I want to ask. I stated very clearly, there is a clear cut between two ideas. And i mentioned industry because you keep asking tools and implementations which are not my focuses.

Comment: And moreover, design before coding is the primary rule and you dont seem to understand that when discussing designs instead of any implementation or tools.

Comment: You didn't ask for the difference. That only happend in your comment 25 min ago. And yes, no matter how often you repeat, the claim that "which method to use" is not independent from the *purpose*. It seems my comments annoy you – can't do anything about that. To repeat what I said a last time: "which way is correct?" reflects a lack of understanding. "The purpose doesn't matter" reflects a lack of consideration."which method is best" without any info on the purpose reflects that you haven't thought about what makes a method good or bad.I've tried to point that out,but you seem to be stubborn.

Comment: I am not playing a word game with you. The underlying context is their differences when you ask which one is preferred. You asked a question without giving me your thought process shows me you are not really here to answer this questions. You don't seem to know VLSI when you even start to ask about tools and things like that. A sequence detector need to consider its tool? Fine. How about MODELSIm? Does that give you a litdab extra info? Context? How about which one to use as an engineer when you are designing this? The question is simple and don't raise another meaningless question here.

Comment: With tools I meant the kind of hardware type you're working on, but yes, even so, what you do also depends on the software used. I might not be here to answer questions - but it might sound like a funky coincidence that I try very hard to get the info out of you that I'd need to give you an answer, plus that I've answered over 500 questions on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Got to admit, for that I would be very tempted to ignore the FSM approach all together, in favour of something like a 5 bit shift register and some simple combinatoric stuff, easier to write, easier to READ (Arguably more important) and very, very obvious in just about any HDL.

5 flipflops and at most one or two LUTS, which is I suppose your second option.

Small FSMs have their place, and in a dense state coding it might actually be more dense then the shift reg approach (by one, maybe two flipflops), but there are reasons why one hot coding for state machines is generally favoured and that is not going to be any better then the shift reg thing, while being harder to understand.

TBH, doing that sort of thing as a FSM strikes me as undergrad excersize, not something that should be done in reality.

Comment: yeah, exactly, that's why I asked for the purpose.

Comment: thank you. That's exactly what I wanna know. FSM is what I have been educated to use. That's why I am confused about these two designs.

Comment: Sequence detectors are very common in education as targets for state machine designs because they illustrate all the essentials in a simple way. This does not make a state machine an automatically good choice for a sequence detector, it just makes it a nice teaching demo. There are cases where it makes sense, once the sequence length becomes long enough that the number of flipflops needed to hold the state is very much less then the length of a suitable shift register for example. This can also depend on the underlying architecture of course, some FPGAs have hardware support that is helpful.

Comment: At least someone answered the question